# filling a form with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a question about filling a form. I have this html.

```
<input type="text" name="" id="voornaam" value="" class="full">
<span class="data-name">Dhr. name lastname</span>
```

When you type you name in the input. The name must be add in the span data name. The name you enter in the input. Should put that in the span.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show a number of text input form fields based on a number entered into another field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827686/show-a-number-of-text-input-form-fields-based-on-a-number-entered-into-another-f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="" id="voornaam" value="" class="full" />
<input type="text" name="" id="achternaam" value="" class="full" />
<span class="data-name">Dhr. name lastname</span>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#voornaam').on('keyup', function () {
    var name = this.value;
    var lastname = $('#achternaam').val();
    $('.data-name').text(name + " " + lastname);
});
$('#achternaam').on('keyup', function () {
    var lastname = this.value;
    var name = $('#voornaam').val();
    $('.data-name').text(name + " " + lastname);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/QKb8J/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code that attaches to the event `keydown` of your textbox and syncs it with the span:

```
$(function() {
    $("#voornaam").keydown(function() {
        $(".data-name").html($(this).val());
    });
});
```

You can find a demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/py3G5/

Answer (score 0):

This will change the text simultaneously with text change

```
 $(function() {
        $("#voornaam").keypress(function() {
            $(".data-name").html($(this).val());
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it works:

```
$("#voornaam").on('keyup', setName);

function setName(event) {
     $(".data-name").html($("#voornaam").val());
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Zhhh/5/)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple javascript:

you can do it all on the element if you want to keep it simple:

javascript:

```
<input type="text" id="source" onkeyup="javascript:$('#dest').text($('#source').val())">
<span id="dest"></span>
```

Whats happening here is that every time you press a key in the input box the javascript event onkeyup fires and the Jquery code copies the value from the input with id "source" to the destination span with id "dest"

Fiddler example: http://jsfiddle.net/dqU5m/

Answer (score 0):

Must the name be added as you type or when you move focus away from the input?

When you type;

```
$(function () {
    $("input#voornaam").change(function (){
        $("span.data-name").html($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Or on focus out;

```
$(function () {
    $("input#voornaam").focusout(function (){
        $("span.data-name").html($(this).val());
    });
});
```

If you are going to be using a lot of this type of functionality it might be worth looking at a framework like [Knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/)